# Grab variable number of tokens – xparse macro

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse, arguments, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to create the following macro:

```
\adddescr{<comma separated list>}{<description 1>}...{<description n>}
```

this macro should print `element -- description \par` accordingly, so that depending on the amount of items in the list, `\adddescr` should read that amount of the following tokens.

Here are some concrete examples:

```
\adddescr{foo,bar,baz}{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}

\adddescr{one,two,three}1{two}three
```

The output result has to be like that

```
foo — aaa
bar — bbb
baz — ccc

one — 1
two — two
three — t
hree
```

---

Here's what I have so far — it currently can only iterate over my list and print it without parsing the following tokens

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\adddescr#1{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tempa_seq {,} {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tempa_seq {
    ##1 ~ -- ~ \par
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\adddescr{foo,bar,baz}{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}
\\

\adddescr{one,two,three}1{two}three
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\adddescr#1{\adddescrx#1,\adddescrstop,\relax}
\def\adddescrx#1,#2\relax{#1\adddescrnext{#2}}
\def\adddescrnext#1#2{ -- #2\par\adddescrx#1\relax}
\def\adddescrstop#1#2{}

\begin{document}

\adddescr{foo,bar,baz}{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}

\adddescr{one,two,three}1{two}three

\end{document}
```

just using a simple recursion here rather than an `expl3` loop.

Comment: Couldn't imagine it can be done so easily and short even without `expl3`, but since I'm still using it for other code I will implement the idea by using quarks. Thanks!